# How to correctly handle a select dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would to display multiple items in a select dropdown.

This is the code. But what i get back are many selects, one for each item i wanted to display in the dropdown.

```
      mostraReferti(id) {
         axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/REFERTOs/' + id)
           .then(response => {
            this.setState({ referti: response.data }, () => {
             console.log("response.data")
                console.log("THIS.STATE", this.state);
              })        
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }

   render() {
     const refertiItems = this.state.referti.map((referti, i) => {
      return (
        <RefertiItems key={referti.hash_referto} item={referti} />
      )
     })
 <Form>
 <Label for="type" text="Referto" />
            <div className="custom-select">
            {refertiItems}
            </div>
 </Form>
```

And RefertiItems is :

```
 render(){
     console.log("SONO DENTRO")
 return (
     <div className={styles}>
     <div  className= "custom-select">
     <Label for="type" text="Codice Referto" />
     <select
       name="codiceReferto"
       placeholder="Selezionare Referto"
      onKeyPress={this.onEnter}     //allows you to move to the next panel with the enter key
       value={this.codiceReferto}
       onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
         <option default value="vuoto"></option>
             <option>{this.state.item.tipo_esame}- 
{this.state.item.data_esame}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have an issue with formatting. It is really difficult to understand something from code with wrong indents.

To fix your main issue you don't need to repeat your `select` component, just repeat `option`s and pass it inside your `select` component, for example:

```
render() {
     return (
          <Form>
               <Label for="type" text="Referto" />
               <div className="custom-select">
                    <RefertiItems items={refertiItems} />
               </div>
          </Form>
     );
}
```

RefertiItems:

```
render() {
    const refertiItems = this.props.items.map((referti, i) => {
        return (
            <option key={referti.hash_referto}>
               {referti.tipo_esame}-{referti.data_esame}
            </option>
        )
    });
    return (
        <div className={styles}>
            <div  className= "custom-select">
                <Label for="type" text="Codice Referto" />
                <select
                    name="codiceReferto"
                    placeholder="Selezionare Referto"
                    onKeyPress={this.onEnter}
                    value={this.codiceReferto}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                >
                    <option default value="vuoto"></option>
                    {refertiItems}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```